# bounded box collision detection in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection

Here is the overlay of the program. I'm working in visual studio 10 , c++ with opengl/glut. I am trying to create a maze(which i generate from an input file). Then i import two models from  3dstudio max with a obj loader(glm). And one of the models(mo) will be moving around the maze. So i added a bounding box around him and also around the walls of the labyrinth . I also drawn the box around mo and it seems to move/rotate along with the character. But for some reason (maybe i'm not doing it in the right place) collision test never detects anything. I will let the code do the talking , and if you have any questions i'll be glad to straighten them out.Prepare for code now.

```
//bounding boxes
struct BoundingBox
{
    Vector3D max;
    Vector3D min;
};
BoundingBox *box_mo;
BoundingBox *static_box[400];

void initbox(BoundingBox *b){
    b->min.x=100000;
    b->min.y=100000;
    b->min.z=100000;
    b->max.x=-100000;
    b->max.y=-100000;
    b->max.z=-100000;
}

BoundingBox *CreateCollisionBox(GLMmodel *model,GLMgroup *object){
/* GLM doesn't store each vertex together with the object that owns it. It doesn't have that notion. In GLM object don't have vertex, they have triangles. And each triangle is actually an index in the triangle list of the object.*/
    BoundingBox *boxx=(BoundingBox*)malloc(sizeof(BoundingBox));
    initbox(boxx);
    for(int i=0;i<object->numtriangles;i++){
// for each vertex of the triangle pmodel1->triangles[object->triangles[i]]
// calculate min and max
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            GLuint index=model->triangles[object->triangles[i]].vindices[j];
            GLfloat x = model->vertices[index*3 +0];
            GLfloat y = model->vertices[index*3 +1];
            GLfloat z = model->vertices[index*3 +2];
            if(boxx->min.x>x) boxx->min.x =x;
            if(boxx->min.y>y) boxx->min.y =y;
            if(boxx->min.z>z) boxx->min.z =z;

            if(boxx->max.x<x) boxx->max.x =x;
            if(boxx->max.y<y) boxx->max.y =y;
            if(boxx->max.z<z) boxx->max.z =z;
        }
    }
    return boxx;
}

void AddCollisionBox(GLMmodel *model,GLMgroup *object){
    //box[boxindex]=CreateCollisionBox(model,object);
    box_mo=CreateCollisionBox(model,object);
    //boxindex++;
}
// A GLMmodel has a chained list of groups, each group representing an object. 
// Each object has a name (the name you gave it in 3D Studio Max or Gmax).
// Let's you have 10 walls in your scene a few other objects as well and you want to 
// create collision boxes just for the walls and you do not want to make a collision box 
// for one of your objects. You could name all your walls
// like this: Wall1, Wall2, ..., Wall10. If you wanted to add collision boxes just to them 
// you could go through all objects in the scene and if their name contains "Wall" add them.
// with this one: strstr
// Basicly this function does just that: if you want to add boxes for the walls you would call it like this: DefineCollisionBoxes(model,"Wall"); 
void DefineCollisionBoxes(GLMmodel *model,char *name){
    GLMgroup *group = model->groups;
    while(group){
        if(strstr(group->name,name))
            AddCollisionBox(model,group);
        group=group->next;
    }
}

bool Collision(BoundingBox *b,GLfloat x,GLfloat y,GLfloat z){
    return x <= b->max.x && x>= b->min.x && y<= b->max.y && y>= b->min.y && z<= b->max.z && z >= b->min.z;
}

bool CollisionTest(BoundingBox *a,BoundingBox *b){
    /*bool collision=false;
    for(int i=0;i<static_boxes;i++){
        for(float x=static_box[i]->min.x, y=static_box[i]->min.y,z=static_box[i]->min.z ;x<=static_box[i]->max.x && y<=static_box[i]->max.y && z<=static_box[i]->max.z;x+=0.1,y+=0.1,z+=0.1){
            if(Collision(a,x,y,z) == true)
                collision=true;
        }
    }
    return collision;*/
    if(a->min.x <= b->max.x && a->max.x >= b->min.x && a->min.z <= b->max.z && a->max.z >= b->min.z && a->min.y <= b->max.y && a->max.y >= b->min.y)
        return true;
    return false;
}

void drawBox(BoundingBox *b){
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(b->max.x,b->max.y,b->min.z);
    glVertex3f(b->min.x,b->max.y,b->min.z);
    glVertex3f(b->min.x,b->min.y,b->min.z);
    glVertex3f(b->max.x,b->min.y,b->min.z);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(b->max.x,b->min.y,b->max.z);
    glVertex3f(b->max.x,b->max.y,b->max.z);
    glVertex3f(b->min.x,b->max.y,b->max.z);
    glVertex3f(b->min.x,b->min.y,b->max.z);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(b->max.x,b->max.y,b->min.z);
    glVertex3f(b->max.x,b->max.y,b->max.z);
    glVertex3f(b->min.x,b->max.y,b->max.z);
    glVertex3f(b->min.x,b->max.y,b->min.z);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(b->max.x,b->min.y,b->max.z);
    glVertex3f(b->min.x,b->min.y,b->max.z);
    glVertex3f(b->min.x,b->min.y,b->min.z);
    glVertex3f(b->max.x,b->min.y,b->min.z);
    glEnd();
}


//display function
void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //setup view
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    camera.render
    //read from file, create walls and characters 
    //place model mo in front of the third person camera always
    Vector3D positionn;
    positionn = camera.position + camera.forward*5;

    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.88f,0.75f,0.49f);
    //here i move my character and calculate bounding box at each frame for him
    glTranslatef(positionn.x,-0.42f,positionn.z);
    glScalef(0.7f,0.7f,0.7f);
    glRotatef(angle,0,1,0);
    drawMo();
    DefineCollisionBoxes(pmodel1,"body"); // actual function call
    drawBox(box_mo); //draw bounding box
    glPopMatrix();

    //test if the character collides with any of the walls - not working
    for(int i=0;i<static_boxes;i++){
        if(CollisionTest(box_mo,static_box[i]) == true){
            printf("collision");
        }
    }


    //swap buffers
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: `I will let the code do the talking` This isn't how Stack Overflow works, what is the actual practical problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: Well i already stated, the problem is that CollisionTest never returns true meaning the detection isn't working. I draw the boxes for each object and they all seem to be working just fine so that really leaves me with no idea of whats wrong. If i draw one of the collision boxes and it rotates and moves along with the character doesn't that mean that the structure (the principle of it) is working fine ? So why doesn't collision test work ?

Comment: Could you shorten your code so that we don't have to wade through it all and figure out what parts are important?

Comment: Ok i re-edited my post, i kept the functions for creating bounding box if you wish to look at them. The main concern is in the display function where i try to see if the objects collide, the printf message never shows up even if i fly around through all the walls

Comment: That is a lot of code to debug... since you are using Visual Studio, why don't you turn on debugging, execute code step-by-step & see the variable values, put breakpoints in essential places etc. An art of good programming involves knowing how to debug! Because we all make bugs...

Comment: Do you ever add bounding boxes to the `static_box` list?

Comment: Yes i add them.I tried checking for collision between static boxes(the walls since they are touching) and the printf works. So the problem is my characters bounding box.I want to try a different approach.I know my initial position, what if i create a predefined box for the character, would that work? And how would i make it rotate/move with the character. LE:i think the problem with the character bounding box (even though when i draw it , it moves with the character) is that it is allways in the same position.I checked the valus of min/max x and are always the same , even after moving characte

Comment: It look as if you are testing if a box is inside of a box (You have only && no ||) so it seems to me that unless the entire box is contained you will always get false

Comment: I changed the statement to something like (a->min.x <= b->max.x && a->max.x >= b->min.x) || (a->min.z <= b->max.z && a->max.z >= b->min.z) || (a->min.y <= b->max.y && a->max.y >= b->min.y) and it always prints "collision" even though i don't have any. The previos with only && is corect, "tested it on paper"

Comment: As far as i can figure it the bounding box for the character(box_mo) always stays in the initial position, i only translate the drawing of it. So how can i create the box from the current position of drawMo() ?

Comment: Point in box(0 being min 1 being max): x0 <= x <= x1 AND y0 <= y <= y1 AND z0 <= z <= z1 BOX collision - This should be tested for any of the 8 boxes points. I can hardly see how you can do with what you have now.

Comment: Well the box is defined by two points(minx,miny,minz) and (maxx,maxy,maxz) meaning two opposite corners

Comment: It still implies 8 points. you can probably optimize the check but I don't think what you have is enough.

Comment: Also if your bounding box is rotated around you will have no choice but testing all points since the min and max will change. You should find the new locations for all box points

Comment: Ok but first how can i create the box at each frame from the current position of the character. I tried something different, i created a new sphere ,translated it and tested if the center of the sphere(so a point) is inside the characters box, and it worked. So my box always stays in the same place even though i call the function every frame, why is that ? why isn't the box created with the new coordinates

Comment: I will try and find time to give you an answer. The reason I only hinted the solution in the comments is that I don't have the time right now to write a detailed answer. However I'm sure that if you google "opengl collision detection" you will get plenty of results. But in order to do it correctly you will have to implement (or take from somewhere) a matrix and vector library to do the calculations correctly. BTW - if you want someone to receive your comments without checking your page use @ with the user name like @user1272703 at the beginning of the message

Comment: Sure, i will apreciate if you find the time to write something down. I  worked all day trying to solve this problem, googling and bookmarking the entire web and didn't come up with a solution. The problem(i did multiple tests) is definitely the characters box.I need to somehow create a new box every frame with the new values. Or even another method if it solves the issue, just don't know what else to try.I will be keeping on eye on the topic, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to give an outline on how to solve the collision problem. For simplicity I will make the following assumptions:

1. We have a coordinate system the maze exists within.
2. Both the camera and the model are transformed into this coordinate system.
3. The only transformation performed on the walls in order to get them to that coordinate system is pure translation without any rotations or scaling.
4. The character will be translated,rotated and scaled.
5. You don't want to check if you will collide but if you collided.
6. You have or you will write or acquire a vector and matrix library

If we use these assumptions we can represent each wall using a  rectangle in 3d. And since we assumed the maze is neither rotated nor scaled we can do it once and store it in an array or a B-tree or what ever. (Note that selecting the right data structure to store your world for calculations can greatly increase performance)

The character moves around the the maze and we assumed that it can be both rotated and scaled. The easiest way to decide if the character has collided with anything is to calculate the bounding sphere of the object. Once you have you can for the sake of the collision detection store just two points. The center point of the sphere and any arbitrary point on the sphere.

Once the character is taken to the correct position in the maze you apply the exact same transformation to the two mentioned points. You either do this using your matrix library or you can query the MODELVIEW matrix after transforming the character. You can do this by calling 'glGetFloatv` like this:

```
GLfloat model[16]; 
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model);
```

Once you have transformed the two points you can find the distance between them - this will be the distance an object has to be away from the transformed center point to avoid collision.

Now the last thing to do is go over the relevant planes and check point to plane distance using the transformed center point and the calculated distance. You then need to make sure that the projected center unto the plane falls within the rectange.

And here is an outline of the program (No real code here just comments and function abstractions)

```
void drawCharacter(Matrix4f const & charMatrix);
void drawMaze(Matrix4f const & mazeMatrix);
//Will return MAX_FLT to indicate out of rectangle condition
float distanceToRectangle(Vector3f const & point, Rectangle3df const & plane);
vector<Rectangle3df> wallPlanes;
Vector3f centerOfCharSphere;
Vector3f pointOnCharSphere;
//Initialization
/*
1. Go Over maze create planes for all walls
2. Calculate character sphere and extract two points: The center of the sphere and a point on the sphere
*/

//Render
/*
Calculate the charMatrix - The matrix that takes the character from object CRS to maze CRS
Calculate the translation matrix for the maze (mazeMatrix) - the matrix that translates the maze into place
*/

Vector3f transformedSphereCenter = charMatrix.transform(centerOfCharSphere);
Vector3f transformedPointOnSphere = charMatrix.transform(pointOnCharSphere);
Vector3f R = transformedPointOnSphere - transformedSphereCenter;
float safeDistance = R.length();
for(vector<Plane3f>::const_iterator it = wallPlanes.begin(); it != wallPlanes.end(); it++)
{
    if(distanceToRectangle(transformedSphereCenter, *it) <= safeDistance)
       printf("collided\n");
}

/*
Setup projection matrix
Setup the modelview matrix for the camera
*/
drawMaze(mazeMatrix);
drawCharacter(charMatrix);
```

I hope this puts you on the right track

Comment: thank you sebastian, very helpful. All assumptions are true, i only need a matrix library (or work with the modelview as you said). I will try this, since at the moment i only have a sphere collision test which is fine for what i need it right now but i will need to enhance it a bit later on, so thank you for your answer. I will keep the question a few more days and if not will chose your answer.